# Warning replace value pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an error trying to replace the value

```
table.loc[table['Column1'].str.contains('Unnamed'), 'Column1'] = np.NaN

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: Are you trying to assign `np.NaN` if `table['Column1']` contains `Unnamed`?

Comment: try using `table.at` instead of `table.loc`.

Comment: Yes if table contains Unnamed change to NaN, because after that, I will go fill NaN by first values

Comment: table.at is the same error

Comment: solved: table=table.copy() before this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
table=table.copy()
include before the code

Answer (score 0):

You could use the apply method

```
def changer(x):
    if 'unnamed' in x:
         x= np.NaN
    return x

df['column'].apply(changer)
```

Comment: I need to contain, not ==

Comment: Thanks, but not working yet
table['Column1'] = table['Column1'].apply(changer)
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
If I try to table['Process'].apply(changer) is not change to NaN